# Arreglo como atributo en java

Tags: java

Tengo una duda, quiero crear un objeto tipo ProductosMed el cual almacena los datos de medicamentos con los sgtes campos
codigo, nombre, laboratorio, fecha de vencimiento y un arreglo con las drogas que contiene el medicamento,

```
package ejercicio5;
public class ProductosMed {
    private int costo;
    private String fechavto;
    private int codigo;
    private String nombre;
    private String Lab;
    private String[]drug;
    public ProductosMed(int codigo, String nombre, String Lab, String fechavto, String[] drug) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.Lab = Lab;
        this.fechavto = fechavto;
        this.drug = drug;
    }
```

El problema es al querer cargar los datos me marca un error en mi IDE, podria alguien señalarme y ayudarme a corregir el error, trate de utilizar el constructor para cargar los datos pero tambien me marca error

```
package ejercicio5;


public class PrincipalProductosMed {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       // (int codigo, String nombre, String Lab, String fechavto, String drug[])
        ProductosMed[] n;
        n= new ProductosMed[5]; 
        n[0]= new ProductosMed(248734,"Ergodolanet","Gramon","22/04/2020",("dipirona,cafeina"));
        System.out.println(n[0]);
    }
    
}
```

El error es este

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable
> source code - Erroneous ctor sym type: ejercicio5.ProductosMed.
> at
> ejercicio5.PrincipalProductosMed.main(PrincipalProductosMed.java:14)
> Command execution failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException:
> Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
> at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
> at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
> at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:982)
> at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:929)
> at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:457)
> at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
> (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
> (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build
> (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
> at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
> at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
> at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced
> (Launcher.java:282)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode
> (Launcher.java:406)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error? ¿Qué estás intentando hacer en esta línea? `n1[1] = {248734,Ergodolanet,Gramon,22/04/2020,{"dipirona","ergomina","cafeina"}};`

Comment: No somos magos, sin ver tu error, dificil ayudarte.. lo que si, el codigo de tu main no tiene sentido...

Comment: Edite mi código nuevamente, podrian volver a revisarlo en cuanto al error lo añadi en mi edición

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero de todo, la forma en la que asignas valores a tu variable `n[1]` es incorrecta y de ahí viene tu primer error, la forma correcta de inicializar la variable seria mediante el constructor tal que así:

```
String drug[] = {"dipirona","ergomina","cafeina"};
n1[1] = new ProductosMed(248734,"Ergodolanet","Gramon","22/04/2020", drug);
```

Aparte el constructor no te hubiera dejado meter el array  `drug` de la forma que lo estabas haciendo porque se pensaría que son parámetros distintos unos de otros y no un array, por lo que lo mejor es crearte un array auxiliar y ese asignarlo como parámetro.
Además si tus parámetros son del tipo String recuerda ponerlos entre comillas si son la cadena de caracteres directamente.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me sirvió mucho tu aporte!